# Specifying Tomcat 7 to use port 8443 only in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

Normally, I configured my Tomcat 7 to perform redirect from port 8080 to 8443. Below is the portion of the configuration and everything works as expected.

**server.xml**

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
    connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
<!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 This connector uses the 
    JSSE configuration, when using APR, the connector should be using the OpenSSL 
    style configuration described in the APR documentation -->

<Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
    keystoreFile="conf/somestore" keystorePass="somekey"
    maxThreads="200" port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Only today, I decided to removed the first connector from configuration. However after I hit start the server button in Eclipse everything seems fine except the message says Starting Tomcat 7 never ends.

[image]

and eventually this:

[image]

By the way, this issue only appears in Tomcat within Eclipse. Is it possible that Eclipse is still trying to access the application through the old port ? Any pointers is much appreciated.

**UPDATED**

After I double clicked the server instance, I am only able to see two ports number under `Ports` section.

1. Tomcat Admin Port which is 8005
2. SSL Port which is 8443

Comment: This might be similiar to the issue I am facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265348/tomcat-from-wtp-ignoring-assigned-port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just goto the tomcat configuration console by double clicking on tomcat under the servers .
Check the port specified there .
If it doesn't help , delete the server and install the tomcat again in eclipse. It only takes a matter of seconds .
[image: Server Console]

Also please try exiting all the tomcat processes from windows and then try to start the tomcat from eclipse once again .

Comment: As you suggested I have removed and added the server, however I still get the same error.

Comment: Please stop all the processes from windows .. Can you also check whether you have started the server explicitly from windows ??

Comment: I have checked there's no other processes running on the same port by using `telnet localhost 8443` in MS-DOS command prompt

Comment: Can you increase the timeout from eclipse and try ? ALso try starting the server on a different port .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Originally I had both a secure and non-secure port open and when I removed the non-secure connector, I had the same issue with Eclipse saying it failed to start.

I resolved the issue by putting a non-secure connector back in.
I am guessing Eclipse tries to access the application to verify it is running and doesn't handle secure ports very well.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse makes a copy of the server configuration and saves it under the "Servers" project.

In the Server View, double clic your server name and when configuration window opens you can edit under "Ports" section.

Edited***

You can go further by opening the "Servers" project, then editing server.xml directly looking for the "Connector" tag that holds the current 8080 port.

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7390/9559799161_3a152c1ac1_o.jpg

Comment: I am able to see only two ports, 8005 for Tomcat Admin and 8443 for the deployed application.

Comment: That's weird, but you can go further by opening the "Servers" project and under your server folder you can see the copy of the server configuration for Eclipse. Then you open server.xml, look for the Connector tag that currently holds 8080 port and change it.