# How to use HTTPS on localhost on Tomcat?

Tags: ssl, https, tomcat8

I am using Apache Tomcat 8 and also have .cert file and the .key file. But I am unable to understand how to turn on the HTTPS mode. I want the APR implementation which uses OpenSSL by default. I tried to change the server.xml file in conf folder according to the documentation but after that Tomcat failed to start and I have delete it and use new unzipped files to start. How can I turn on SSL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the APR is already installed and configured on your Tomcat, you could have something like this in your server.xml:

```
Connector protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       SSLCertificateFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.crt"
       SSLCertificateKeyFile="/usr/local/ssl/server.pem"
       SSLVerifyClient="optional" SSLProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"/>
```

Take a look at this tutorial [tutorial](https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-ssl), it was quite helpful for me.

Also [this one](https://books.google.es/books?id=drAR_LEU_NsC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=tomcat%20connector%20protocol%3D%22org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol%22&source=bl&ots=YM20XC95bC&sig=oXf8R0nChac1uTDzTxTb1HjUZ9Q&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=tomcat%20connector%20protocol%3D%22org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol%22&f=false) could be interesting.

Comment: thanks.. this worked for me.. but I'm getting error that the identity of website is not verified. how to i add my certificate to trusted source. it is a self-signed certificate.

Comment: It's not working on eclipse. I tried changing the server.xml on workspace/.metadata/.pligins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/conf. Eclipse is opening localhost:8443 on simple http protocol but not on HTTPS while using eclipse.

Comment: If it is a self-signed certificate, your browser will let you know that the CA of the certificate is unknown, but still you should be able to work with it. If you don't want that to happen you can get a trial certificate from one of the authorities and it will work fine.

Comment: What happens if you force it to https on eclipse? I guess that's another tomcat, right? Did you install APR also there?

Comment: That's not another tomcat. Eclipse uses its own configuration files for running the server without tampering the data in the server folder. Also, configuring the server.xml ran the tomcat on HTTPS mode but only for once. It again runs only on http mode on port 8443.

Comment: I've never used a Tomcat inside Eclipse, but in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352041/specifying-tomcat-7-to-use-port-8443-only-in-eclipse) they talk about it, maybe it can help you too

Comment: Ok leaving eclipse behind and focusing only on tomcat, tomcat is giving SSL connection error while using HTTPS and working well on http://localhost:8443. Can you please solve this?